# Which sections of Shacharit can be delayed?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shacharis-morning-prayer

If one is in a rush, and he only says Birchot Kriyat Shema, the Amida, and Alenu, what parts of Shacharit can he return and say later (after ending his prayer by saying Alenu and doing distracting activities)? Is there an order to which these parts of Shacharit must be recited? Can Pitum HaKetoret be said twice, one directly after the other?

Comment: Indeed, why say it twice at all.....?

Comment: @Yehuda My siddur (Edot HaMizrach) has Pitum HaKtoret twice, one after Korban Tamid and the other after Shir Shel Yom.

Comment: As does mine (Siddur Matok Mid'vash nusach Ashkenaz) - why is it in there that way though?

Comment: I'm not sure why it is arranged that way

Comment: I quickly asked a rabbi about this and he said that it is fine to say both of Pitum HaKtoret, Korban Tamid, Tachanun (although it is preferable to say it directly after Amidah), and Pesuke DeZimrah (without Baruch SheAmar and Yishtbach).

Answer (score 4):

The question has many factors to consider.

**Birchas Hashachar** - If one did not say Birchas Hashachar beforehand, the [Mishna Berura 52:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.52.9?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) says that he must say it afterwards, besides Birchas Hatorah and אלקי נשמה, which are a subject of a machlokes;

> ומ"מ יאמר - ר"ל שמחוייב לאמרם אחר התפלה אם לא אמרן קודם התפלה. ועיין לעיל בסימן מ"ז ס"ח לענין ברכת התורה ובמ"ב שם בסקי"ז מה שכתבנו בשם א"ר ועיין בפרי חדש שכתב דגם ברכת אלהי נשמה לא יאמר אחר התפלה שכבר יצא בברכת מחיה מתים ועיין בפמ"ג שכתב דמדברי הרמ"א לא משמע כן וכן בספר מאמר מרדכי חולק עליו וכן בשע"ת בסי' ו' כתב דמסתבר דלא יצא וכן משמע מביאור הגר"א בסימן זה ועיין בבה"ל. ומ"מ יותר טוב לכתחלה לצאת אליבא דכו"ע דהיינו שאם התחיל כבר להתפלל ושכח מקודם ברכת א"נ =אלוקי נשמה= יכוין בפירוש בברכת ונאמן אתה שאינו רוצה לפטור בזה ברכת א"נ =אלוקי נשמה= ואז לכו"ע יברכנה אחר התפלה דנהי דברכות א"צ כונה לצאת מ"מ היכא דמכוין בפירוש שלא לצאת שפיר דמי עי"ש עוד [פמ"ג] ועיין בבה"ל שכתבנו דאם שכח ברכת התורה והתחיל ברכת ק"ש יכוין בפירוש בברכת אהבה רבה לפטור ברכת התורה ויראה ללמוד תיכף לאחר התפלה ויצא בזה אליבא דכו"ע:

The [Aruch Hashulchan](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Orach_Chaim.52.8?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) mentions an issue with הנותן לשכוי בינה and מתיר אסורים as well

As far as if he needs to say it immediately after or it can be some time later, The [M"B in 52:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.52.10?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) says preferably it should be before the zman tefilla but it can be said all day if needed.

**Korbanos** - The [Biur Halacha Siman 1](https://www.sefaria.org/Biur_Halacha.1.5.1?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) says one should say it in a Shul and before davening if there is time. The [Ketzos Hashulchan 14:1](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7720&st=&pgnum=79) says that if there is no time you should skip it all and say it after davening (presumably, preferably in Shul).

**Pesukai Dzimra** - The Shulchan Aruch 52:1 says that you should say it after davening without Baruch Sheamar and Yishtabach. The [Aruch Hashulchan](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Orach_Chaim.52.4?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) explains that you MAY say it afterwards but you don't HAVE to;

> ומזה נתברר כמה גדול כוח תפילה בציבור: שלא לבד שמקצרים בשירות ותשבחות של פסוקי דזמרה אלא אפילו מבטלין אותן לגמרי, דכל בלא ברכה אינו כלום. וזה שכתב שאחר כך יקרא כל פסוקי דזמרה – אינו לחובה, שהרי רב נטרונאי גאון כתב הטור בשמו שלא יקרא אותן אחר כך כלל. אלא שרבינו הבית יוסף בספרו הגדול כתב דוודאי כוונתו בברכה, דבלא ברכה הלואי שיאמר כל היום כולו, עיין שם. אלמא דלא לחיובה קאמר אלא כקריאת מזמורים בעלמא. ולפי זה גם מי שמקצר בפסוקי דזמרה, כמו שנתבאר לעיל – יכול לאומרם אחר התפילה כקריאת מזמורים בעלמא.

R' Chaim Kanievski in Orchos Yosher (page 95) says you MUST say it right away after davening.

**Tachnun** - The [Shulchan Aruch 131:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.131.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) says that one should not speak between Shemone Esrai and Tachnun. The [Mishna Berura 131:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.131.2?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) says that if one did speak he should still say Tachnun. R' Chaim Kanievski (Ishei Yisroel Teshuva 231) says that if the Chazzan said Kaddish by mistake and skipped Tachnun, he should not go back (R' Shlomo Zalman argues), which seems to indicate that once you went further in davening you cannot go back to say Tachnun.

**Ashrei and Uva Letzion** - The [Rema in 132:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.132.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) says that the minhag is that an individual can say Uva Letzion although it is recommended to do everything you can to say it with the Tzibbur. The Minchas Yitzchak (Chelek 9 8:2) says that if you were in middle of davening and could not be mafsik you can say it afterwards.

**Pitum Hakatores** - The [Mishna Berura 132:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.132.14?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) gives a few reasons for saying it twice of which none seem to fit in this case of after davening to say it twice in a row:

> (יד) ובוקר אחר התפלה - וצ"ע למה אנו אומרין אותה בשבת ויו"ט אחר מוסף והלא הקטורת קודמת למוספין לכו"ע והיא שייכא לקרבן תמיד ואפשר דכונתנו ליפטר מתוך ד"ת ובכתבים איתא שהטעם להבריח הקליפות ובשל"ה כתב לאמרו קודם תפלה ואחריה:

If it is to finish from Torah, once is enough. If it is to chase away Klipos, seemingly once would be enough, and according to the Shel"a it seems that it is once before and once after not twice after.

Comment: "besides Birchas Hatorah and אלקי נשמה, which are a subject of a machlokes" He only mentions machlokes on those two but there are others that are also subject to machlokes, see aruch hashulchan.

Comment: I knew I had seen somewhere that those 2 others that were an issue, but I missed it in the Aruch Hashulchan. Thank you!